# Mongodb object within array within array

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, object, mongodb-query

I'm having this JSON data structure:

```
{
data :
{
    fields_data :
   [
     [
       {
         key1 : val
       },
       {
         key1 : val
       }
     ],
     [
       {
        key2 : val
       },
       {
       key2 : val
       }
     ]
]
}
}
```

I'm having hard time to query this, I'd tried to use the in and the elemMatch in other ways but with no success.

one of the queries I've tried :

```
{
    "data.fields_data": {
        $in: [{
            $in: [{
                $elemMatch: 
                    {
            $elemMatch : {
                        "key1": "random text"
                        }
            }
                }]

        }]
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nested `$elemMatch` should work here:

```js
db.collection.find{
  'data.fields_data': {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        key1: val
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But you should consider getting rid of nested array here. For example, you could use array if objects instead:

```
{
  data: {
    fields_data: [{
      data: [
        { key1: val },
        { key1: val }
      ]}, {
      data: [
        { key2: val },
        { key2: val }
      ]}
    ]
  }
}
```

It will allow you to query your documents using simple dot notation:

```
{ 'data.fields_data.data.key1': val }
```